# How to convert a csv file to a dataframe in Python 3.6

Tags: python, csv

Im trying to tackle the Kaggle Titanic challenge. Bear with me, as Im fairly new to data science.  I was previously struggling to get the following syntax to work: my previous question(Reading CSV files in Python 3.6, using IntelliJ IDEA)
[Reading CSV files in Python, using Jupyter Notebook through IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454458/reading-csv-files-in-python-using-jupyter-notebook-through-intellij-idea?noredirect=1#comment87922405_50454458)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,Dataframe

titanic_df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
titanic.head()
```

However, using the below code, I am able to open the file and read it/print its contents, but i need to convert the data to a dataframe so that it can be worked with.  Any suggestions?

```
file_path = '/Volumes/LACIE SETUP/Data_Science/Data_Analysis_Viz_InPython/Example_Projects/train.csv'

with open(file_path) as train_fp:
    for line in train_fp:
#         print(line)
```

This above code was able to print out the data but when I tried passing 
'file_path' to:

```
titanic_df = pd.read_csv('file_path.csv')
```

i received the same error as before. Not sure what Im doing wrong. I KNOW the file 'train.csv' exists in that location because 1) i put it there and 2) its contents can be printed when pointed to its location.

So what the heck am I doing wrong??? :/

Comment: `titanic.head()`; you called your DF `titanic_df`, not `titanic`

Comment: Do not ask the same question again just because you did not get the answer in the first place.

Comment: It's a typo anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`read_csv` will create a Pandas DataFrame. So, as long as your file path is right, this following code should work. Also, make sure to use the `file_path` variable and not the string "file_path.csv"

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = '/Volumes/LACIE SETUP/Data_Science/Data_Analysis_Viz_InPython/Example_Projects/train.csv'

titanic_df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
titanic_df.head()
```

Comment: Your code carries over the OP's `NameError`

Comment: Not any more :-)

Comment: But from the scattergun question, I'm inclined to think that was the actual issue :)

Comment: I think there is a confusion between the `file_path` variable and the string "file_path.csv"

Comment: @ Julien Spronck Thanks! I figured out what my problem was... 1) I did need to adjust my code a bit by removing the single quotation marks from file_path.  However, my biggest issue was for some reason whenever I start a new project in IntelliJ IDEA, it doesnt carry over my settings and so my SDK was not configured for the project through the Jupyter Notebook GUI in IntelliJ. Ughhh.... such a headache.  Thanks again all!